# Detect if an application uses gtk or qt

Tags: graphics, gtk, qt

Previously, my laptop used Ubuntu 14.04 without trouble, but after passing to Ubuntu 16.04 (not upgrading, but formatting), I've some rendering problems. Since I cannot put here specific details because I don't know what is exactly happening, I'm searcher for the error yet.

My current assumption is that, the rendering issues are only affecting gtk applications (for example, some PDF images are being rendering poorly in `evince`, but not in `Okular`).

What I want to know if there's a way to know, in the easiest way as possible, if an application is a gtk or Qt one, to open different applications, see which shows bad rendering, and which library has been use to build that software.

Comment: Rather than assuming that it's a gtk/qt problem, why don't you tell us more about your **specific** problem. Edit your question to include some screenshots. Cheers, Al

Comment: You might make use of `ldd` to see which dynamic libraries the binary links: for example `ldd $(which evince) | grep 'gtk\|qt'`

Comment: Actually, Qt applications have uppercase letters so you would grep for `'gtk\|Qt'`. Since libraries can be load at runtime, it might be more reliable to just start the program and inspect paths to the mapped files using `pmap -p $pid | grep 'gtk|Qt'`

Answer (score 3):

An application can use Qt and Tk and Gtk (despite this is generally -*but not always*- a very bad practice).

So the only way is to start the app and examine `pmap` output using app's pid, as Lekensteyn proposed in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you *could* use `ldd` to list the libraries used by a binary program. Here, we also filter the list for  toolkits `gtk`, `qt`, and `tk` including their version numbers:

```
ldd "$(readlink -f "$(type -p INSERT-APP-NAME-HERE)")" |
grep -Poi '\b(lib)?\K(gtk|qt|tk)([^a-z/]*\d)*(?=[^/]*\.so\b)' | sort -u
```

However, this will not work if the program is a script file (for instance a python or perl program) or uses a script/program to start the actual binary. The latter is pretty common, for instance `firefox` and `libreoffice` use a starter script. In that case, you can inspect the starter manually to find out the path of the actual program. But even then, the output of `ldd` may not be complete. At least for Firefox 90, the list printed by `ldd` is missing nearly all of Firefox' dependencies.

Therefore, it may be easier and safer to start the program, run the following script, and then click on the window for which you want to know the toolkit:

```
grep -Poi '\b(lib)?\K(gtk|qt|tk)([^a-z/]*\d)*(?=[^/]*\.so\b)' \
/proc/"$(xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3)"/maps | sort -u
```

Although this might fail if `xprop` cannot find the PID of the clicked window. In that case, you can replace `$(xprop ...)` by something like `$(pgrep -o INSERT-APP-NAME-HERE)`.

Comment: with variable: `INSERT_APP_NAME_HERE="gnome-disks"; ldd "$(readlink -f "$(type -p $INSERT_APP_NAME_HERE)")" | grep -Poi '\b(lib)?\K(gtk|qt|tk)([^a-z/]*\d)*(?=[^/]*\.so\b)' | sort -u` ..the xprop window clicker is pretty cool.